# Why don't the effects of time dilation cancel out?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

Say we have two objects: **A** and **B**. In **A**'s IRF, **B** moves with velocity *+v*. Then, **B** undergoes time dilation, and from **B**'s perspective, the passage of time for **A** has sped up.

However, in **B**'s IRF, **A** moves with velocity *-v*. Then, **A** undergoes time dilation, and from **B**'s perspective, the passage of time for **B** has sped up.

This is a contradiction, the passage of time in **A** can't have sped up relative to **B**. What am I missing?

Comment: A _sees_ B's time going more slowly, but B is _unaware_ of that observation, so obviously _B's time does not change_.  This is an area that is taught _awfully_ in most courses I have seen, and I think it is at the root of what you are missing.